# accessing the element in the following element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know how to get element in jquery by id or class or by using find but I have an element like the following and I want to find it and change the text inside(here is test):

```
<text x="524" text-anchor="end" zIndex="8" style="cursor:pointer;color:#909090;font-size:9px;fill:#909090;" y="170">test</text>
```

but the problem is that here this text element does not have any id and I have so many text element in the html file so is there anyway that I can access just this text element(I also can not add id to this text because is created by plugin) ?

Comment: Is that element always in the same position in the DOM?

Comment: `$( "text[x='524']")` something like this?

Comment: Well, you'll have to analyse what properties of this particular text element make it unique. Or, you can use jQuery to loop through every text element and perform some decision making.

Comment: _"is there anyway that I can access just this text element"_ You can always access an element via the hierarchy, but we can't see it since you didn't post it. Also, what's with the `<text>` element?

Comment: Hi @PatrickQ  No the position is not the same

Comment: @HamedMinaee What makes this particular element unique? I mean, how do you know, that this is the one you want?

Comment: thanks @AlexB.  because it has always the same text inside(for example always test)

Comment: In this case, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select elements based on content, use `$(":contains('text')")`

See: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Ans then you can edit the text like this.

```
$("text:contains('theTextYouKnowIsInside')").html("newText");
```

Comment: Thanks @AlexB. I used this and I think it should work but it does not:$( "text:contains('test')" ).html( "");

Comment: I did but still the text does not disappear!

Comment: @HamedMinaee, if the elements are created by a plugin, it is possible, that they get created _later_ then your jQuery code gets executed. So, try adding a timeout before executing `$( "text:contains('test')" ).html( "");`, or test the functionality by creating a button that executes this code and click on the button when you are sure, that your text element exists.

Comment: PS: Also, I was wrong - the single quotes are required.

Answer (score 1):

You could access via any of following methods :

```
$("text[x=524]").html("here is test");

$("text[x=524][y=170]").html("here is test");

$("text[y=170]").html("here is test");
```

here is the [demo JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rqUxy/2/)

Comment: Oh, that's right, I didn't notice that :) But the 'fill' made me curious and I investigated. It turns out it actually isn't supported by any browser. But the text got colored anyway, because there is aslo a `color` property I didn't see before :)